# Best way to get last message and unread message count from twilio channel android

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions

I have checked all the possibility to get the last message and unread message count from the Twilio channel. When tried to get the last message from the channel that I faced threading issue and also it was very slow.

So can anyone help me to achieve these things.

Comment: What threading issue did you face? What was the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Channel descriptor contains [unread message count](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/4.0.4/docs/classcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1ChannelDescriptor.html#ae98269fefdae6e8852346d45696b16de) but to get last message index you will have to retrieve full Channel from the descriptor (that's a server roundtrip) and then [get the message from the channel by its index](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/4.0.4/docs/classcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1Channel.html#a6d712d482c8a365096010fc0b3f003f0) (that's another roundtrip), so it's going to be relatively slow. Best is to offload this operation to background thread and update view lazily when this information is available.